# Rails dates in rails console

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, date

My app create and save events with form into a mysql database. I use something like that

```
event = Event.new .... start_date: Time.now ...
```

I'm french, my local time is GMT + 200, and Time.now use local Time machine.
But in rails console i have a problem, for example if i create an event at **2016-09-12 18:30:00** when i run

```
Event.all
```

in rails console i see :

```
#... <Event id: 5 ... start_date: 2016-09-12 16:30:00 ...
```

i have 2 hour lag, but when i do

```
e = Event.find 5
e.start_date
```

i have result

```
Mon, 12 Sep 2016 18:30:00 CEST +02:00
```

The good time.
I see mysql log and my request insert the correct date :

```
INSERT INTO `events` ... 2016-09-12 18:30:00'
```

I precise my app works perfectly, i just want to understand that.
Thanks

*Edit #1* 
Content of my **config/application.rb**

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
config.time_zone = 'Paris'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails defaults all times to UTC so it saves all records in the database to this default timezone. But you already changed the application.rb to Paris so the console show the correct time. But for the database it doesn't change a thing.

You can use:

```
event = Event.new .... start_date: Time.now.in_time_zone ...
```

This way Rails skips the default time_zone to use the time_zone in your application.rb when adding to the database.

Comment: No i check my database and i have corrects dates. I have just a problem when i use method like first or all. The console show the correct time when i use event.start_date

Comment: And is use `config.active_record.default_timezone = :local` so it change all things in the database because with this instruction rails use local timezone when it pulls date in database. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

Comment: Yeah i didn't see your edit yet when i answered that. Normally in the application.rb it is '# config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)''

Comment: oh okay. I dont understand because my app works perfectly, just when i run .all are .first ... i have a lag of two hours